# I have difficulty understanding the following sentence fragment: ". . . cuts real deep calling miss homecoming a cow."

Tags: slang

I heard this line in a PS4 game, where two teenage girls quarreled about a boy they both like.

For one thing, it seems to me that there's no verb in this sentence fragment. Second, the way I break the sentence down is as follows:does the word cuts function as a noun and the words *real deep* function as adjectives?

> - cuts: nouns
> - real deep: adjective
> - calling miss homecoming a cow: present participle clause

For another thing, I cannot catch the real meaning. I know that "Miss Homecoming" is one who is most well liked by the entire high school, but what does "Miss Homecoming" have to do with deep cuts?

Comment: the expression to **cut deep** is informal and means: to cause emotional pain to a person. Calling miss H a cow [subject]  cuts deep [predicate].

Comment: This being casual dialog, the dummy subject "it" has been elided: "It cuts real deep, calling miss homecoming a cow" > "referring to the homecoming queen in this derogatory fashion inflicts significant psychological distress."

Comment: Can you give a full sentence, plus some context before and after?

Comment: lets not miss the extremely **sexist** allusions to stereotypical female traits like weakness, insecurity, vanity, fragility(untrue, unjust, but widely repeated) . I say a bit more in a comment to an answer below.  *Without taking the sexism and stereotypes played up into account, I don't think you get the full meaning.*

Answer (score 2):

Just add "it" at the beginning. It is implied in the sentence: "*It* cuts real deep calling miss homecoming a cow."

> - "Cuts" functions as the verb, not as a plural noun
> - "Real deep" (or "really deeply") functions as an adverb here
> - "Calling Miss Homecoming a cow" is actually the subject in the sentence

To make it more clear, here's how the sentence would look like in a more direct order:

> "Calling miss homecoming a cow cuts really deeply."

Or,

> "It cuts really deeply."

where *It* refers to the subject *calling Miss Homecoming a cow.*

The meaning of "cuts real deep" is that calling Miss Homecoming a cow is a big offense, one that inflicts emotional pain. "Cuts real deep" is a figure of speech that likens the offense (i.e., calling Miss Homecoming a cow) to a cut to the flesh.

Comment: This is probably a sarcastic comment, because someone who has been voted Miss Homecoming can be confident she is not generally considered fat and slow-witted like a cow.

Comment: There is a sort of humor of a sort that laughs at the reaction of others but I think their meaning is more mean spiritedly straightforward.  I'd say that 1) they're making assumptions that Miss Homecoming is overly obsessed with how others perceive of her -- the nick name emphasizing the "miss" instead of "homecoming queen", calls up sexist female stereotypes of weakness and histrionics 2) that a "miss" would be fragile and lack confidence and have her shallow world shattered.   The speaker finds shattering a shallow world a good thing. **it is an extremely sexist remark**